# Python - AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I receive an error

`ClassFile.append(filelines)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'`

while trying to write a file. It is about writing a file about pupil's scores, their name, lastname, classname (Just enter class as `Class 1`)a scorecount of how many scores and their scores. Only their last 3 scores are to be kept in the file. I don't understand what this means.

Here is the code

```
score=3
counter=0

name=input('Name:')
surname=input('Last Name:')
Class=input('Class Name:')

filelines=[]

Class=open(Class+'.txt','r')
line=Class.readline()
while line!='':
    Class.append(filelines)
    Class.close()

linecount=len(filelines)
for i in range(0,linecount):
    data=filelines[i].split(',')
```

Comment: this simply means that a file object  does not have a method called append()

Comment: I'm not exactly what's going on, but you are opening a file in read mode (the `'r'`), then trying to write to the file afterwards (`'append'`). Maybe you need to open it with `'r+'`, so you can both read and write. Further, files have the `write`/`writelines` methods for writing, not `append`. You are using  python3, right? If so, tag your question as such, it helps :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got your append code all mixed up; the `append()` method is on the `filelines` object:

```
ClassFile=open(CN+'.txt','r')
line=ClassFile.readline()
while line!='':
    filelines.append(line)
ClassFile.close()
```

Note that I also moved the `close()` call *out* of the loop.

You don't need to use a `while` loop there; if you want a list with all the lines, you can simply do:

```
ClassFile=open(CN+'.txt','r')
filelines = list(ClassFile)
ClassFile.close()
```

To handle file closing, use the file object as a context manager:

```
with open(CN + '.txt', 'r') as openfile:
    filelines = list(openfile)
```

Answer (score 3):

`ClassFile` is an object of type `_io.TextIOWrapper` which does not has any attribute `append`. You are mistaking it to be an object of type List. It seems in place of ClassFile.append(filelines) you want something like `filelines.append(line)`. 
If you want to write something into a file, open it in write or append mode (depending on your need) and write into it the string you want.