# Python - Error - AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to insert a column into a csv file and increment the column by one.
I am getting the error above in the subject:

```
with open('C:\\temp\\XXX\\names.csv','r') as rf:
    with open('C:\\temp\\XXX\\Testcopyx.csv','w') as wf:
        for line in rf:
            wf.write(line)                
            wf.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(0, 0 + len(wf)))
            # wf
wf.close
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593981/python-attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-append

Answer (score 0):

Below I use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to transcribe a csv file from one file to another, adding a column at the end that increments along with the rows

```
import csv

infile  = 'C:\\temp\\XXX\\names.csv'
outfile = 'C:\\temp\\XXX\\Testcopyx.csv' 

with open(infile, newline='') as rf, open(outfile, 'w+', newline='') as wf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(rf)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(wf, [*reader.fieldnames, "New ID"])  # Add the new column name
    writer.writeheader()
    for count, row in enumerate(reader):
        row.update({"New ID": count})  # update the row to have the new column
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Very close but it is adding in a blank row

Comment: At the top?  Does your original file have headers?

Comment: Or after every line?  In that case open each file with `newline=''`

Comment: I added newline=''     still getting a new line after every row

Comment: import csv

infile  = 'C:\\temp\\XXX\\names.csv'
outfile = 'C:\\temp\\XXX\\Testcopyx.csv' 

with open(infile) as rf, open(outfile, 'w+') as wf:
    newline=''
    reader = csv.DictReader(rf)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(wf, [*reader.fieldnames, "Count"])  # Add the new column name
    writer.writeheader()
    for count, row in enumerate(reader):
        row.update({"Count": count})  # update the row to have the new column
        writer.writerow(row)

Comment: Thank you for your help on this question

Comment: @JohnT Did that solve it?  I notice you put `newline=''` in the wrong place in your code.

Comment: No still getting the new line