# Write new text data to text file without overwriting the previous data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a String list that keeps changing with iteration. I want to write the list of elements to a text file. When the list changes, I  want to update the text file without overwriting the old data.

I tried doing this using the append method, but I don't know why it is giving me an error each time I run the code.
It gives the following error:

> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'

```py
matches = ['Steve', 'Kaira', 'Wokes']

with open('textfile.txt','a') as f:
    for match in matches:
        f.append(match)
```

Comment: Next time when the list is  ['Michael', 'John' ,'Lita'] ...I want the text file to be...  Steve Kaira  Wokes Michael John Lita

Comment: What made you think that `f` had an `append` method?

Comment: I thougt it would, i am a newbie to python.

Comment: Try `f.write(match + '\n')` instead.

Comment: @khelwood  You solved my problem , f.write works.

Answer (score 0):

The file object does not have any attribute `append` is the cause of your error. There is no function called `append()` for a file object in python. Instead use `write()` in append mode.
See this link: [Python - AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593981/python-attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-append)

See this example:

```
urls = open("urlfile.txt","a")
for image_url in image_urls:
    urls.write(image_url + "\n")
urls.close()
```

Comment: Since the OP's code was correctly using a `with` block, it is unfortunate to give them code doing things a worse way.

Comment: I was just pointing out an example of using write() instead of append(); this being the code I had at hand

Comment: By itself, your answer isn't wrong. But given the context of the OP's question, I suggest catering your answer towards a similar setup to OP's, i.e. using the same variable names (e.g. `f`) and the same structure (e.g. the Pythonic `with`-block), unless there is good reason not to. That way, readers will better understand what changed: "Oh, so I need to change .append to .write." Some might be confused how open() and .close() appeared or why it is used instead of the `with`-block.